# How can I serve static files with nginx but use a slightly different url for tornado?

Tags: nginx, python, reverse-proxy, tornado

I have a directory structure I want to serve, that contains files as binary and some meta-information about them as json. for some directories, I need to compute some things on the fly and serve that. I want to compute and serve that information using tornado.

Here is an example:

```
> ls /manufacturers/*
  audi/
  audi.json
  mercedes/
  mercedes.json

> wget http://localhost/manufactures/audi.json
  returns the json file using nginx static serving
> wget http://localhost/?diesel
  returns a json file with manufactures that 
  create cars with diesel engines computed by and using tornado
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your use-case is "serve static files if they exist, otherwise send everything to tornado", you can do that with `try_files`:

```
upstream upstream_tornado {
    server http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    # ...or wherever
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /path/to/wherever;

    try_files  $uri @tornado;

    location @tornado {
        proxy_pass http://upstream_tornado;
        # Other proxy stuff e.g. proxy_set_header
    }
}
```

Comment: Using this right now. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

You can check with nginx whether `?diesel` is being called by looking for `$arg_diesel` in the `location = /` block.

```
location = / {

    if ( $arg_diesel ) {
        proxy_pass http://tornado;
    }

}
```

`location = /` is **not** the same as the `location /`. `location = /` will only be called for requests that aren't in a folder such `/?diesel`, but not `/somepath/?diesel` whereas the `location /` will match everything.

Documentation: http://nginx.org/r/location